# esp32/ws2812b power issue

Tags: power-supply, led-strip, ws2812b

I'm building a little circuit to handle two 5m led strips with an ESP32. ESP32 is a d-duino-32 OLED clone you can find in ebay/aliexpress sites.

Also bought a 5v 20a power supply. One path powers the esp32 with a 1000uf capacitor and a 1ohm/5.1v zener diode. The other path goes directly to both strips with a 2000uf in the middle.

The first time I turn on, I see on OLED display info I programmed. Leds are off because didn't programmed the code yet. If I turn off and on again, I can measure the correct voltage but ESP32 does not start.

If I turn off again, wait some minutes and turn on again, works again.

If I remove the led strips, works always.

It is supposed the 20A power supply should be enough to handle the 300 leds x 60mA each = 18A plus ESP's 500mA although all leds are off initially.

What can cause this to fail?

EDIT:

Circuit: [image: Circuit]
Photo: [image]

Comment: Draw a circuit and post it. Don't expect others to interpret your words consistently or correctly.

Comment: yep, and not only draw a circuit. At such high currents, the actual wiring becomes a resistive element, and plays a role in the circuit, so please also add a photo.

Comment: Done, photo and circuit uploaded

Answer (score 1):

Replaced capacitors with lower ones (10uF/100nF and 470uF) and problem solved.